# Return which substring is in a cell from a list of substrings

Tags: arrays, excel, text, excel-formula, substring

**Problem**

Given a list of substrings in a range in Excel, for example:

*Substring table*

```
[A1:A3]  
Apple  
Banana  
Carrot
```

I wish to return which of these substrings is present in a cell containing text, such as:

*Text Cell*

```
[A5]  
The Apple fell from the tree
```

Method / formula would return: `Apple`

**Reason**:

Each month I will import a few hundred cells which contain text and need categorizing. The most common substrings will be in the substring range at the top, the idea being the imported text cells will have an adjacent column with a formula which outputs which one of the substrings if one is present, saving a lot of user time. A desired output example would be:

**Desired Output**

```
*Table of text cells* | *Output referencing substring table* [A5:B5]  
The Apple fell from the tree | Apple  
A Carrot grows in the ground | Carrot  
There was a bag of rotten Apples | Apple  
Watch out for that Orange |  
The monkey ate the Banana | Banana
```

**Closest formula via tinkering & research**

The closest I have gotten is a formula which returns if a substring is present (returning a 1 or 0) being:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$3,A5)))
```

Using this formula & the above 'Desired Output' example, I would see:

```
[A5:B5]  
The Apple fell from the tree | 1  
A Carrot grows in the ground | 1  
There was a bag of rotten Apples | 1  
Watch out for that Orange | 0  
The monkey ate the Banana | 1
```

This was recommended on this forum for a TRUE/FALSE test which I was unable to adapt to my needs. Any advice is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B5:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$3)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$1:$A$3,A5))),1))
```

And copy down

Comment: Additionally thank you for the formatting on my question, I am new and will apply the format as you have should I ask another question in the future :)

Comment: Thanks Scott for the speedy reply, the logic is brilliant, re-commenting as Scott's response was updated to perfectly fix my issue from my first comment!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2016, you can use `TEXTJOIN` in an array formula:

```
{=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2:A$4,A5)),A$2:A$4,""))}
```

As it is an array formula, don't forget to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this, I currently have 2010 but will be upgrading soon and will test it out to learn.